# Supervisord using environment variables in command

Tags: supervisord, flower

My supervisor configuration file

```
environment=USER=%(ENV_FLOWER_USER_NAME),PASS=%(ENV_FLOWER_PASSWORD)
command=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/flower --basic_auth=%(ENV_USER}:%(ENV_PASS)
```

When I start supervisord, I receive the following error

> Restarting supervisor: Error: Format string
>   'USER=%(ENV_FLOWER_USER_NAME),PASS=%(ENV_FLOWER_PASSWORD)' for
>   'environment' is badly formatted

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the leading `s` in formatting environment variable name. Here is [sample config file](https://github.com/Supervisor/supervisor/blob/master/supervisor/skel/sample.conf#L8).

You should use

```
environment=USER=%(ENV_FLOWER_USER_NAME)s,PASS=%(ENV_FLOWER_PASSWORD)s
command=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/flower --basic_auth=%(ENV_USER)s:%(ENV_PASS)s
```

For readability

```
environment=
    USER=%(ENV_FLOWER_USER_NAME)s,
    PASS=%(ENV_FLOWER_PASSWORD)s

command=/usr/local/opt/python/bin/flower 
            --basic_auth=%(ENV_USER)s:%(ENV_PASS)s
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable if this form is prefixed with `%(ENV_NAME)s` to the name.

docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
  ENVIRONMENT: production
  PORT: 8011 # port uwsgi
```

supervisord.conf

```
[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini --http :%(ENV_PORT)s
```

saludos :)